# Struggling to read a node with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Here is my XML response from an API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCertificateResponse xmlns="http://url.com">
      <GetCertificateResult>
        <ReturnValue xmlns="">
          <Status>Success</Status>
          <Message/>
          <CertificateNumber/>
          <URL/>
        </ReturnValue>
      </GetCertificateResult>
    </GetCertificateResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I reaq the status node? I've tried so many combos:

```
            $getCertificateXMLResponse = simplexml_load_string($getCertificateXMLResponse);

        echo  $getCertificateXMLResponse->GetCertificateResponse->GetCertificateResult->ReturnValue->Status;
```

Comment: Use SOAP PHP extention to handle SOAP Requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it with Xpath

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soap, NULL, NULL, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');

$result = $xml->xpath('//Status');
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: Are you able to tell me why my method isn't working? Is it because it's SOAP, so there's more to it than reading a normal XML response? Thanks!

Comment: It's because you don't start your method in the head of the tree.
In your example, you should use something like:
$getCertificateXMLResponse->children("soap", true)->Body->children()->GetCertificateResponse->GetCertificateResult->ReturnValue->Status

Comment: The original solution works just fine which is enough for me! Cheers for the input

Answer (score 0):

it's... ugly.. but works

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('a.xml'),0,false,'');
$namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces(true);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('empty', $namespaces['']);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$status = array_shift($xml->xpath("soap:Body/empty:GetCertificateResponse/empty:GetCertificateResult/ReturnValue/Status"));
echo $status->asXML();
```

i'm curious to see more elegant solution.

and indeed take a look at things like [nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/).